# Debian package depend on libgit2

Tags: cmake, debian, cpack

I am using `cpack` to create a Debian package. My package needs libgit2 at runtime. I have

```
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "libgit2")
```

in my `CMakeLists.txt` file, but the installer fails to find `libgit2`.

I found `libgit2-27` is available but seems that the number 27 is going to change in the future.

How can I ask installer to install `"libgit2-" + <any number higher than 24>"`?

Comment: Packages with names like this basically want to prevent you from automatically pulling in a newer version, because a version number change will also imply a change in the API and/or feature set. Compare with how many, many, *many* packages have a hardcoded dependency on `libc6`; there will have to be a long and complex transition if `libc7` is ever released.

Answer (score 0):

Similar as described in the [Debian documentation](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html):

```
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "libgit2-25 | libgit2-26 | libgit2-27")
```